# Does Apache have built in DDOS protection? I'm getting interesting JMeter results

Tags: php, apache, jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing

I was recently asked by a client to load test their server to see if it could handle 10,000 concurrent users. To do this I've been using JMeter but getting less than favorable results.

Let me just say that this is my first time using jmeter so I'm not super sure of what Im doing, BUT here's what I've found.

On a test of 1000 concurrent users all launched at once and each user going to 2 pages, the failure rate is 96%. This seems bad...like really really bad.

Is there something that could possibly be going wrong in JMeter? All I'm doing is sending HTTP GET requests to their server.

I don't know what kind of plan the client is on but I do know that they are using GoDaddy as their provider and in my experience GoDaddy's "unlimited" bandwidth is rather limited. Is this the problem OR and I'm really hoping that this is the case, is the Apache server for the website blocking the repeated attempts.

I get an error saying `org.apahe.http.com.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to ~~~.com refused`.
Is this the server being smart?
Or the server being bogged down?

Thanks in advance for your help, let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: is 10,000 concurrent users a realistic metric? (a lot?) less than 1% of the sites on the internet would get that traffic. and Go Daddy is one of the worst hosts available. If they really need to handle that traffic, you need to do some serous tuning of a multi server system. AWS comes to mind, but i think the client is blowing smoke

Comment: The client is a reality TV figure so I guess there is a chance that they will have that many concurrent hits but trust me, I thought the exact same thing.

Comment: either charge him, and use the time to learn how to really scale a project, or just explain that its not going to be an issue.

Comment: What is your test setup like? If I assume you are using single jmeter instance, the client itself will be bottleneck. I haven't come across any recommended figure, but whenever I have run more than 250 threads on my dual core linux jmeter client, I start getting all kinds of error response. But as soon as I distribute the load using distributed jmeters, things start behaving as they are expected.

Comment: @Manish It appears that I can run close to 1000 without trouble but any more than that and it gets really unhappy. I'm fairly confident that the clients server just sucks because I ran the same test against my own website and got 0 errors. Switched back to the clients and got 97% connection failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache can't protect you from ddos attacks, but you can use some modules to reduce risks, they are: [mod_qos](http://opensource.adnovum.ch/mod_qos/) and [mod_evasive](http://www.zdziarski.com/blog/?page_id=442).

If you are using shared hosting from GoDaddy, seems you are loading all websites in one server and Godaddy may block your site or they may treat your load testing as ddos attack. For experiments you need isolated VDS server or cloud server.

If you want protect your project you can:

- Use load balancer
- Use caching tool
- Use firewall protection
- OS tuning
- Use CDN